# Is bindToLifecycle() is necessary to switch ON/OFF/AUTO flash every time after creating preview in CameraX library

Tags: android, android-camerax

As I understand from many implementations such as :

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

https://proandroiddev.com/android-camerax-preview-analyze-capture-1b3f403a9395

After every use case in CameraX implementation **cameraProvide.bindToLifecycle()** method needs to be called.

For example, if I need to switch *ON* the FLASH_MODE of the camera from the default *OFF* mode, then again bindToLifecycle() method needs to be called.

The disadvantage with this approach is that for a second or two the preview is removed and re-attached which doesn't feel like a smooth transition for an app.

**Is there any better practice available or it is the limitation?**

I Have attached a sample code below:

```
   private void bindCameraUseCase() {
    int screenAspectRatio = getAspectRatio(previewView.getWidth(), previewView.getHeight());
    int rotation = previewView.getDisplay().getRotation();
    preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build();
    cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(lensFacing)
            .build();
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setFlashMode(flashMode)
            .build();
    // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());
    camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
}
```

And to toggle flashlight:

```
    private void toggleFlash(){
    Log.d(TAG, "toggleFlash: "+flashMode);
    switch (flashMode){
        case ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF:
            flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON;
            flashButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_24dp);
            break;
        case ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON:
            flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
            break;
        case ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO:
            flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
            break;
    }
    bindCameraUseCase();
}
```

**I'm using CameraX version - 1.0.0-beta04**

Comment: If you're looking to control the torch, as in turning it on and off, you can look into using [`CameraControl.enableTorch(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#enableTorch(boolean)). it doesn't require re-binding the use cases, you can get a `CameraControl` instance after the binding happens.

Comment: No, I'm looking about flash when clicking the picture specifically when building imageCapture object. If flash mode is changed then i need to call bindToLifecylce() again right, which will remove the preview for a second or two which I feel is not smooth transition ? Or Is there any other way ?.

Comment: If you need to change the flash mode after the `ImageCapture` has been set, you can simply use [`ImageCapture.setFlashMode(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#setFlashMode(int)), it defines the flash mode for subsequent captured images. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for and it's working fine.  Thank you.
One small follow up question.  ImageCapture use case is already bound to the lifecycle. How is changing the functionality of use case (such as a flash mode for my case)  is working without re-bind to lifecycle? 
Any relevant resources to understand would be fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable or disable the flash during an image capture after you've created an `ImageCapture` instance and bound it to a lifecycle, you can use [`ImageCapture.setFlashMode(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#setFlashMode(int)).

Regarding your question about the difference between setting the flash mode before vs after binding the `ImageCapture` use case, AFAIK there isn't much of a difference really. When you take a picture by calling `ImageCapture.takePicture()`, a capture request is built using different configuration parameters, one of them is the flash mode. So as long as the flash mode is set before this call (`ImageCapture.takePicture()`), the output of the capture request should be the same.

CameraX currently uses Camera2 under the hood, to better understand how the flash mode is set when taking a picture, you can take a look at [CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#FLASH_MODE).

Answer (score 0):

I see ImageCapture.flashMode only has effect during we build with initial configuration, ImageCapture.Builder() etc.
But if you want to enable/disable flash dynamically, you will have to use the following.

```
camera?.cameraControl?.enableTorch(enableFlash)
```

If you are wondering what camera is? Captured it from documentation.

```
// A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
// camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
)
```